# Troubleshooting connections between strips of WS2811 Addressable RGB LEDs

Tags: soldering, led-strip, troubleshooting

I'm hoping for help troubleshooting a light array I built for my son's room. I strung together 8 strips of WS2811 addressable RGB LEDs (30 per strip). I soldered all the strings together, and tested them prior to mounting. Whole strand lit up beautifully. Then, I mounted them onto his desk, and now the first strip lights, and only the first LED of the second strand lights and that one LED is significantly dimmer.

No problem, I think, one of the connections just came loose. But it doesn't *seem* as though I have any bad solders, and jiggling the wires around doesn't really cause any change in the lone weak LED on the second strip.

- I put a multimeter on the end of the first, well-behaved, strip. No value reading across +5V and Gnd. But *no reading* wouldn't explain how the second strip has one light with some small amount of juice.
- I mounted onto the painted wood surface using the adhesive on the back of the strips, and the back does have the exposed copper pads. I figured that the paint on the wood would be sufficiently insulating, but could there be voltage drop from the mounting?
- I'm running this with an ESP32, and have a dedicated 5V 2A power supply powering the LEDs.

I'm sure it's a bad solder, but without getting any reading from the good strip's +5V and GND, I'm a little confused. Also, there's clearly some current moving on since the second strip is lighting up a little bit. I'd like to troubleshoot it before I have to unmount the whole dang thing and redo the wiring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a cold solder on the ground pad. Not sure why I got no reading on the multimeter, but whatever.